# How do I convert an hebrew database from latin1_swedish_ci to utf8?

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a news website in Hebrew. All the Hebrew data in the database is stored in latin1_swedish_ci encoding.

Beyond converting the column encoding through phpMyAdmin, I need to convert the data itself.

Is there any easy way of doing this?

Daniel.

Comment: Can latin1 even contain hebrew characters?

Answer (score 0):

Since `latin1` does not include Hebrew characters, you have a special form of mess.  However, it can be "fixed".  But first, we need to know what encoding you had when doing the `INSERTs`.  Perhaps `hebrew`, perhaps `utf8`?

To find out, do

```
SELECT col, HEX(col) FROM tbl WHERE ...
```

For example: `א`, in utf8 would be hex `D790`; in `hebrew`, it would be `E0`

If the text is utf8 (mostly Dxxx), we can do the 2-step ALTER to fix it:

```
ALTER TABLE Tbl MODIFY COLUMN col VARBINARY(...) ...;
ALTER TABLE Tbl MODIFY COLUMN col VARCHAR(...) ... CHARACTER SET utf8 ...;
```

If `hebrew`, then I think 3 steps are needed:

```
ALTER TABLE Tbl MODIFY COLUMN col VARBINARY(...) ...;
ALTER TABLE Tbl MODIFY COLUMN col VARCHAR(...) ... CHARACTER SET hebrew ...;
ALTER TABLE Tbl MODIFY COLUMN col VARCHAR(...) ... CHARACTER SET utf8 ...;
```

The first 2 (of the 3) steps un-lies about what the encoding is; the 3 ALTER converts both the column definition and the bytes (E0 -> D790, etc).

**Update**

```
CREATE TABLE h2u ( c VARCHAR(9) CHARACTER SET latin1 );
INSERT INTO h2u (c) VALUE (UNHEX('D790'));
SELECT c, HEX(c), LENGTH(c), CHAR_LENGTH(c) FROM h2u;
+------+--------+-----------+----------------+
| c    | HEX(c) | LENGTH(c) | CHAR_LENGTH(c) |
+------+--------+-----------+----------------+
| ×   | D790   |         2 |              2 |
+------+--------+-----------+----------------+

# Now to fix it...
ALTER TABLE h2u MODIFY COLUMN c VARBINARY(9);
ALTER TABLE h2u MODIFY COLUMN c VARCHAR(9) CHARACTER SET utf8;
SELECT c, HEX(c), LENGTH(c), CHAR_LENGTH(c) FROM h2u;
+------+--------+-----------+----------------+
| c    | HEX(c) | LENGTH(c) | CHAR_LENGTH(c) |
+------+--------+-----------+----------------+
| א    | D790   |         2 |              1 |
+------+--------+-----------+----------------+
```

In what way does your test case differ?

Comment: It's in utf8 (turned א to D790).
But the second line:
ALTER TABLE `pages` MODIFY COLUMN `title` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8;
left an empty column.